# How do I have links open a specific tab inside a Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have 5 links at the bottom of a webpage. They link to a Bootstrap modal with tabs that match the links on the webpage, but it always defaults to the first tab/tab content. How can I have the links open the correct tab/tab content in the modal.

Here is my code for the modal and the links that are on the webpage:

```
<div id="LegalModal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">

    <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#283c5a; border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        <h3>rateGenius Legal Terms & Agreements</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="tabbable"> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a class="tab1" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Terms of Use</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Mobile Privacy Policy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Security</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">Licensing</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content" id="tabs" style="padding:30px;">

                <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                    <h1>Terms of Use</h1>

                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                    <h1>Privacy Policy</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
                   <h1>Mobile Privacy Policy</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
                    <h1>Security</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5">
                    <h1>Licensing</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<ul class="list-unstyled" style="text-align:center;">
    <li><a href="#LegalModal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" data-toggle="modal" >Terms of Service</a></li>
    <li><a href="#LegalModal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" data-toggle="modal" >Privacy Policy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#LegalModal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" data-toggle="modal" >Mobile Privacy Policy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#LegalModal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" data-toggle="modal">Security</a></li>
    <li><a href="#LegalModal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" data-toggle="modal">Licensing</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Heya, welcome to SO! It would help if you edit the question a bit. Try to remove some stuff that's not necessary (so much text kind of obscures the real problem, and only a small portion of the markup is important anyways), try to take out the "`+`" signs and update the formatting, and last but not least: tell us where you specifically got stuck? (Surely you've tried things: tell us what they were and why those solutions didn't work.)

Comment: Where can I edit my question?

Comment: There's an edit link just below the question's tags. Don't forget to use the question preview a lot: your question gets bumped if edited significantly and it gets the most views (thus chance for an answer) in the early stages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the anchor toggle both the modal and the correct tab by hooking up some custom jQuery to the links:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.legal-tabs li').on('click', function() {
    var tab = $(this).index();
    $('#LegalModal .modal-body .nav-tabs a:eq(' + tab + ')').tab('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="LegalModal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="tabbable"> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a class="tab1" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="tab-content" id="tabs" style="padding:30px;">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
            <h1>Terms of Use</h1>                      
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
              <h1>Privacy Policy</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<ul class="list-unstyled legal-tabs" style="text-align:center;">
  <li><a href="#LegalModal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" data-toggle="modal">Show tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#LegalModal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" data-toggle="modal">Show tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks for your help and it was so easy to implement. Works like a charm.

Comment: @Jeroen how bout the winform version of this?

Comment: @Æthenwulf Erhhmmm what?  Note that my answer is 6,5 years old, but either way, if you're talking about "WinForms", the .NET desktop GUI technology, then this Q&A is not helpful to you at all. It's purely about web technology.