# Trigger an anchor, open a modal and go to the anchor inside the modal

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to make a strange thing. I'll explain the general situation, then go with the step-by-step procedure that i want to do. I have a list of items inside an `<ul>`. When i press an element, a modal has to open. Inside this modal there are the same elements of the `<ul>` but explained in details. When the modal opens i want that the element that i have clicked inside the `<ul>` will be at the top of the `modal body`. Basically an anchor. Now the step-by-step

List of items (`<li><a href="#some_element"></a></li>`)
I click an item(Click me!)
The modal opens, showing the anchor

```
start_modal_body

<div id="some_element"></div>
<div id="not_this"></div>
<div id="not_this"></div>
<div id="not_this"></div>

end_modal_body
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

The modal and the rest of the code are in two separate files

**Edit 2:**

Since i'm using knockout, i can't use jquery to tell the modal to redirect me, this is why i was trying to use an anchor

Comment: are you asking about dropdown menu

Comment: nope, a modal with anchors inside it, i want to be able to be redirected to that anchor inside the modal from outside, but it seems impossible @ruchikajain

Comment: It will require JS. You can use Bootstrap tabs as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028814/how-do-i-have-links-open-a-specific-tab-inside-a-bootstrap-modal, and convert the jquery solution to js/knockout

Comment: @ZimSystem that's the point, i do not want the tabs, i have anchors inside the body and i want to be redirected there once i clicked the link external to the modal

Comment: @ZimSystem Perfect, i think there are either two options: creating a bindingHandler or give up. I can't 'take' the modal directly from the View, i would break the MVVM pattern, i need a bindingHandler that will trigger after the modal has been opened. The problem is that the modal is a custom bindingHandler itself -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a CSS-only answer that might work if you're ok with re-ordering the positions of the anchor sections inside the modal, instead of scrolling to the top.

Wrap the modal buttons on another element an use that element to open the modal. Then the href inside the link will work to target the appropriate anchor...

```
<span data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal"><a href="#a" role="button" class="btn btn-primary">A</a></span>
<span data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal"><a href="#b" role="button" class="btn btn-primary">B</a></span>
<span data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal"><a href="#c" role="button" class="btn btn-primary">C</a></span>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body d-flex flex-column">
                <div id="a">
                    ..
                </div>
                <div id="b">
                    ..
                </div>
                <div id="c">
                    ..
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And use flexbox order to move the targeted section to the top of the modal...

```
.modal-body > div:target {
    order:0;
}

.modal-body > div:not(:target) {
    order:1;
}
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/HraCKrWHII

Comment: This might be the solution! I'll try it right away, it should work